# Avoid read blocks with broken SATA disk

Tags: hard-drive, sata, freebsd

In my FreeBSD system, I have a bunch of SATA disks which are part of a ZFS raid.

When I am starting the system, I see many

```
ATA status: 41 (DRDY ERR), error: 40 (UNC )
RES: 41 40 d8 70 f8 40 81 00 00 00 00
Retrying command
READ_FPDMA_QUEUED. ACB: 60 08 d8 70 f8 40 81 00 00
```

and they come up in an infinite loop. It seems that data is requested from the disk ... reading fails and reading is attempted over and over again. As a result, the system does not boot.

Note that the involved disk is not the system disk (or part of a pool which holds the system), hence it is not needed for booting.

Is there a configuration to avoid this and return with an error immideately such that the system can boot?

Alternatively, it could just return a block of zeros after 1-2 failed read attempts; the RAID configuration would automatically detect this as a read failure.